# Saved Game + Real Time Multiplayer Android

Tags: android, google-play-games, multiplayer, android-savedstate

I want to build a game that has realTimeMultiplayer and support for saved game.

Both functionalities come from the Play Services API provided by android.

The players would invite their friends, play in real-Time, then whenever one player quits, the game is saved and other players are disconnected.

Then when the friends want to play together again, they can load up the game, be placed in the waiting room until all their friends are connected and then resume the game where it was.

Is this a possibility in Android through the Google Play API? How would I go about going from the saved game to the waiting room with the original players?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: Is it possible?  Sure.  How to do it?  Way too big a topic for here, and there's a dozen possible answers depending on your infrastructure (do games save locally?  On a server?  Both?  Any of those are possible answers, but would lead to very different solutions).

Comment: @Gabe Sechan Thanks for the comment. Sorry my question was a bit ambiguous. I meant is it possible to use The Saved Games services from Play Services along with the real time multiplayer service from the Play Services.

Comment: Ok, that's a more reasonable scope. I don't know enough to help, but I'll take away the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Real-time Multiplayer](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer) from GPGS. I think it will give you insight on your questions:

```
-Room initialization
-Room configuration
-Participants
-Auto-matching
-Connected set
-In-game networking
-Invitations
```

You can also use Google's [Firebase for Real-time Events on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-firebase-real-time-events-app-engine#sample).

There's a real-time multiplayer game Tic Tac Toe game sample in this [Github repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/firebase-tictactoe).

Comment: yes I had seen that documentation. There is one key thing I am completely unsure of. Its when players want to resume playing. How do I go about loading all of the players that they were originally playing with and then placing all of them in the waiting room. How do I invite them again?

Comment: no I wouldn't say I need a course on the general topic. My question is quite specific. I'm wondering how to go from saved state saved to Google Play Services, retrieve the user Ids from it and resend invitation to resume game to other users.